# Como insertar un nuevo dato en un array con moongose?

Tags: nodejs, express, moongose

estoy desarrollando un chat con node y mongo DB, uso **express** y establezco una comunicación con la base de datos mediante **moongose**, tengo una colección en la base de datos llamado connections, donde se almacenaran los datos de las nuevas conexiones que surjan, ya puedo insertar las nuevas conexiones dentro de un array llamado activeUsers, el problema que tengo es al momento de que un usuario abra una segunda conexión, para este caso, quiero que el id del socket de la nueva conexión se agregue al array idSocket del usuario, de esta forma las nuevas conexiones se irán agregando al array. He buscado varias formas de hacerlo pero ninguno me dio resultado, para acceder a ese campo e insertar el nuevo dato al array con **moongose**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc31449c379064d5cd09f30"),
    "activeUsers" : [
            {
                    "idSocket" : [
                            "232mnjb3hb3j3jb3jn3jd332"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc31449c379064d5cd09f31"),
                    "user" : "steph"
            },
            {
                    "idSocket" : [
                            "232mnjb3hb3j3jb3jn3jd3dr"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3146dc379064d5cd09f32"),
                    "user" : "william"
            },
            {
                    "idSocket" : [
                            "232mnjb3hb3j3jb3jnrfrd7dr"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc31480c379064d5cd09f33"),
                    "user" : "julie"
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

```js
router.get('/add/:id/:user', async (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var user = req.params.user;

    const data = await Connection.find();
    
    //si la coleccion connections no esta vacia
    if(data.length > 0){
        const findUser = data[0].usersOnline.find( u => u.user === user);

        if(findUser == undefined){
            // si el usuario realiza una nueva conexion, se agrega al array activeUsers
            const newConnection = await Connection.updateOne({
                    $push: {
                        usersOnline: [{
                            user: user,
                            idSocket: id
                        }]
                    }
            }); 
            res.send('New connection saved');
        }else{
            //si el usuario ya habia realizado una conexion, agregar la nueva conexion(id socket) al array idSocket el usuario 
      
            res.send('User exist');

            newConnection = await Connection.findOneAndUpdate(
                { usersOnline: user },
                { $push: {idSocket: [id]} },
                    function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(err);
                        } else {
                            res.send(result);
                        }
                    }
            );  
        }
    }else{
        //si la coleccion connections se encuentra vacia
        const newConnection = new Connection({
            usersOnline: [{
                user: user,
                idSocket: id
            }]
        });
        await newConnection.save();
        res.send('New connection saved');
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código fuente con lo que has intentado hasta el momento a tu pregunta por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu código te comento:

- Falta el campo `usersOnline` en el ejemplo del documento, se entiende que un array de objetos.
- Uso de `callback` con `async/await`:

  ```
  newConnection = await Connection.findOneAndUpdate( 
                           { usersOnline: user },
                           { $push: {idSocket: [id]} },
                           function(err, result) {
                              if (err) {
                                res.send(err);
                              } else {
                                res.send(result);
                              }
                           }
                        );
  ```

  Usas un await para esperar la promesa pero después usas un callback, no se seria necesario este ultimo porque estas usando `async/await`, ya te retornaría el valor. **Importante**, retornaría el valor antes de modificarse, para ello se tendría que agregar la opción `returnNewDocument` a `true`
- Haces un `find` de toda la colección, cuando esta se haga mas grande te afectara en el rendimiento de tu aplicación. Te muestro una solución mas abajo.
- Respondes dos veces, lo cual `express` te lanzara un logs de error:

  ```
       res.send('User exist'); //Aqui respondes

       newConnection = await Connection.findOneAndUpdate(
           { usersOnline: user },
           { $push: {idSocket: [id]} },
               function(err, result) {
                   if (err) {
                       res.send(err);
                   } else {
                       res.send(result); // Respondes de nuevo
                   }
               }
       );
  ```

Te adjunto tu codigo refactorizado resolviendo tu problema y mejorando el rendimiento:

```
router.get('/add/:id/:user', async (req, res) => {
    const {params: {id, user}} = req // Destructuring ES6

    try {
        // Verificamos si existe el usuario en DB
        if (await Connection.findOne({"usersOnline.user": user})) {
            //si el usuario ya habia realizado una conexion, agregar la nueva conexion(id socket) al array idSocket el usuario
            const connection = await Connection.findOneAndUpdate(
                {"usersOnline.user": user}, // Para buscar dentro de un array de objetos
                {
                    $push: {
                        "activeUsers.$[elem].idSocket": id // el "$[elem]" se usa en la opción "arrayFilters", es como una sub-búsqueda
                    }
                },
                {
                    returnNewDocument: true,
                    arrayFilters: [
                        {
                            "elem.user": { // elem es cada objeto del array
                                $eq: user
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );

            res.send('User exist')  // Si es necesario devolver la conexion solo es poner res.send(connection)

        } else {
            //si la coleccion connections se encuentra vacia o no encuentra el usuario en la DB
            const newConnection = new Connection({
                usersOnline: [{
                    user: user,
                    idSocket: id
                }]
            });
            await newConnection.save();
            res.send('New connection saved');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err) // Tratar la respuesta que se quiera en caso de error
    }
});
```

Espero que con esto te haya podido ayudar a solucionar tu problema.

Cualquier cosa, no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de gran utilidad

Comment: me alegro!!! 
@jose, si mi respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema, te agradecería que la validaras como correcta. Gracias!